# Unable to change resolution on multiple monitors

Tags: windows-7, drivers, multiple-monitors, resolution

My Dell Latitude 5420 supports multiple resolutions when it is not connected to any additional displays (As someone would normally expect).

But when it is connected to other displays (Note: Only when the display shows up as a Generic PnP Monitor) i.e for instance a projector, it is unable to change the resolution other than the native resolution of my in-built screen i.e 1366 x 768.

I tried updating the drivers but to no avail. I am required to give a presentation and would prefer a 4:3 resolution which is what my presentation is designed for. Is there any way to solve this issue?

My OS is Windows 7 Service Pack 1 with Intel HD 3000 & Driver Version 9.17.10.3347

Comment: After you install [intel onboard video](https://www.google.com/search?q=intel+onboard+graphics&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=rvdFU62TOoem2AXbqICQBQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg&biw=1920&bih=986#q=intel+graphics+options&tbm=isch&imgdii=_) drivers you can normally right click on the desktop and it will show Intel Integrated Video Options or something to that effect.

Comment: @Sickest Yes, I have tried that. On most projectors and monitors, this seems to work fine with my laptop but in case of a projector which is not connected directly i.e via a projection system/console or simply shows up as a Generic PnP Monitor I am unable to change the resolution. It simply does not show me *any* other options other than the native resolution of my built in screen.